# Create single page site with sliding page effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I have some across this [webpage](http://storyboardtoptemplatedemo.weebly.com/) that has a great single page implementation that I would like to replicate.

I want to be able to switch content boxes (and the background image) using menu links like the webpage. Is there any ready made jQuery plugins that are available?

Comment: So I've figured they've used [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) Although I'm finding it difficult to integrate it with div boxes instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with either any of a dozen carousel JQuery plugins or you could implement Jquery Mobile and get the same sort of effect.

The benefit of JQM might be that your page would now also be mobile ready.

**Edit**

I'm not ordinarily a fan of posting links but in this case the question I think is a little broad for a concise answer so here is a link of some plugins that might do the job for you.

http://www.designrazzi.com/2013/jquery-slider-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

try scrolldeck.js
http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/

or Fathom.js
http://markdalgleish.com/projects/fathom/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>      
    <head>      
       <title>Sample Page</title>           
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-   1.0.min.css" />    
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">    </script>        
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>   
<body>              
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">      
        <div data-role="header">         
            <h1>
                Page 1
            </h1>     
        </div><!-- /header -->      

        <div data-role="content">
            <a id="changePageButton" data-role="button">Change Page!</a>
        </div><!-- /content -->      

        <div data-role="footer">              
        </div> 
    </div><!-- /page -->      

    <div data-role="page" id="page2">         
        <div data-role="header">    
           <h1>
              Page 2
            </h1>     
        </div><!-- /header -->         

        <div data-role="content">  
            <p>Hooray for page 2!</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->         

        <div data-role="footer">         
        </div><!-- /fotoer -->     

    </div><!-- /page --> 

</body>
```

```
$(function() {
    $("#changePageButton").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    });        
});
```